# Get coordinates of selected ( rubbed ) area of image like app Cinemagram

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Get coordinates of selected ( rubbed ) area of image like app Cinemagram

Any Help How will I do the rubbing  for selecting desired image area like app Cinemagram

also I am trying to get the coordinates of Selected ( or rubbed ) image area  like the app

Cinemagram

Comment: You have any idea regarding the animation of the selected portion?
Like how to create gif kind of image of cropped region?

Comment: The animation that occurs in the rubbed region in cinemagram app,that creation.

Comment: Please tell what coding you have done till now  
At what stage you are stuck
Post your relevant snippet
I can not answer your question without any proper description(include some snippet of your coding   and total progress  you have done till now)